# Better way to minimize array elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, array

I would like the array elements to minimize by preserving their orders. For example:

- `3,7,9,7` is given `1,2,3,2` is yielded
- `1,99,90,95,99` is given `1,4,2,3,4` is yielded.

Think array can be ranged btw 0 to 100, exclusively. My try’s time complexity is \$O(n^3 + n)\$.

Can there be more efficient way to solve this?

```
int[] arr = new int[] {2,5,3,5}; // example input


var copy = (int[])arr.Clone();
var num = 101;
foreach(var x in arr)
{
    var min = copy.Min();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length; i++)
    if(min == arr[i])
    {
        copy[i] = num;
    }
    num++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < copy.Length; i++)
{
    copy[i] = copy[i] % 100;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Indents

I've spent a minute struggling to understand that `copy[i] = num;` happens inside the second `for` loop. Please, indent the code to make it readable - you will gain from it in the first place.

#### Your algorithm is \$O(n^2)\$

First, \$O(n^3+n) = O(n^3)\$. \$O(n)\$ can be neglected because it is small compared to \$O(n^3)\$. Second, I don't see any third loop inside the second.

#### Better algo

1. Sort the copy of the array, \$O(n*log(n))\$.
2. Make some search structure to convert a number in a sorted array into its index (map or another array), \$O(n)\$.
3. Change all numbers in the first array to their indexes in sorted array, \$O(n)\$.

Answer (score 1):

This is zero based index and the example is one based index, can add one if need to match.  I didn't do timing test to see if this is faster or even look at memory consumptions.  To me this reads and makes it easier to maintain.  I prefer maintenance over performance unless it's needs to be performance skewed for the area of code it's in.

[SortedList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=net-5.0) takes two values but we don't care about the value so just toss in a bool to make it happy.   Then using the [IndexOfKey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2.indexofkey?view=net-5.0) method that uses a binary search.  Which under the covers uses [Array.BinarySearch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=net-5.0).  Could take SortedList out of the picture and use Array.BinarySearch to do similar to what SortListed is doing if having the bool value that isn't used is a deal breaker for you.

```
public static int[] Positions(params int[] items)
{
    var sortedList = new SortedList<int, bool>(items.Length);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        sortedList.TryAdd(items[i], false);
    }

    var result = new int[items.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i< items.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = sortedList.IndexOfKey(items[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

EDIT:  If you want to avoid SortedList you can do what it's doing pretty simple.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Position(params int[] items)
{
    var distinct = new HashSet<int>(items);
    var clone = new int[distinct.Count];
    distinct.CopyTo(clone);
    Array.Sort(clone);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return Array.BinarySearch(clone, items[i]) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, `Positions(arr).Select(x => x+1)` fixes the final result.

Comment: You can just do 'result[i] = sortedList.IndexOfKey(items[i]) + 1;' instead of looping through again.  I assumed you wanted an array back.  if wanting an ienumerable you can just yield return that statement and change the method signature

Comment: While `SortedList` (being key/value) is alienating given SortedDictionary: why not just use SortedSet?

Comment: @greybeard SortedSet/SortedDictionary doesn't contain IndexOfKey

Comment: @CharlesNRice it is an elegant solution. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

> Can there be more efficient way to [canonicalise values between minV and maxV in an array preserving rank]?

Yes. Let me suggest another mechanism in-stead of *sorting* / *ordering* (the latter being what most procedures with a name derived from *sort* do):
When the range of values maxV - minV is small, use an array about that size to

1. find which values do appear
   (When keeping count of value frequencies, this can be used for *ordering using value counts*: [counting sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#Pseudocode).)
2. assign canonical values
3. map input values to canonical values

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the complexity to `O(N.Log(N))` (on average) at the expense of space by introducing an adjunct array containing the numbers 0..N-1 and sorting it at the same time as the original array.

This will yield a set of indices that you can use to populate a results array like so:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 99, 90, 95, 99 };
int[] tmp = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length).ToArray();
int[] res = new int[arr.Length];

Array.Sort(arr, tmp);
int ind = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
{
    if (i == 0 || arr[i] != arr[i-1])
        ++ind;

    res[tmp[i]] = ind;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", res));  // 1, 4, 2, 3, 4
```